# Split String based on specific character sequence

Tags: java, regex, string, split

so I have input strings looking like this:

> "O2TV, SportTV", Netflix /603605506, 2016-01-02 15:15:01

> yearly subscription, Netflix /602602602, 2016-01-02 10:55:32

> game Of thrones, Netflix /602602602, 2016-01-02 09:49:09

I'm reversing them and trying to split

```
line = StringService.reverseIt(line);//reversing line so we can split it from end
String[] splitString = line.split("([ ./])", 5);
```

But because my regex expression is not correct one, I have incorrect split and it's looking like this:

> Time is = 22:13:11

> Data is = 2016-02-29

> Phone is = 604606321,

> Provider is =

> Note is = recharging of 987654321, Netflix

If I leave just whitespace in regex it's splitting correct but my String has unwanted characters on sides. All input data have the same pattern from backward, it's: whitespace( ) then comma(,) then slash(/) then comma(,). What is the correct regular expression I need to use? Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Parsing comma-separated lines of text, with quoted values: **Use a CSV library,** don't use regex for that.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you for your answer, but they are not only comma-separated. It's whitespace, comma, backslash, and comma again for each line

Comment: @Bonuseto You're misunderstanding the concept I guess. The strings you've provided are CSV. Just because you're parsing the content differently doesn't make it invalid CSV. You just have to apply your split logic (Date from Time) on the extracted CSV values.

Comment: @Andreas but I'm not splitting the only date from time, I'm splitting all five parts: Time, Data, Phone, Provide and Note, and I need to split them based on whitespace, comma and backslash

Comment: Use CSV parser to split on comma (this will handle the case where comma is inside quotes). Then you can split other parts using String#split however you like.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is way too long for a comment...

When treating the lines as CSV with any library or custom solution of your choice, you'll get the following in one form or another (in these examples, `line[]` is just a simple `String[]`):

**Example 1:**

```
"O2TV, SportTV", Netflix /603605506, 2016-01-02 15:15:01

line[0] = "O2TV, SportTV"
line[1] = Netflix /603605506
line[2] = 2016-01-02 15:15:01
```

**Example 2:**

```
yearly subscription, Netflix /602602602, 2016-01-02 10:55:32

line[0] = yearly subscription
line[1] = Netflix /602602602
line[2] = 2016-01-02 10:55:32
```

**Example 3:**

```
game Of thrones, Netflix /602602602, 2016-01-02 09:49:09

line[0] = game Of thrones
line[1] = Netflix /6026026022
line[2] = 2016-01-02 09:49:09
```

From your desired output, I'd guess that `line[0]` is always the `provider`.

The phone number is always `line[1].substring(line[1].indexOf('/'))`
Netflix can be extracted by `line[1].substring(0,line[1].indexOf('/'))`

The string `recharging of 987654321` isn't contained in any of the examples.

For the time and date part, you'd either just create a `LocalDateTime` object from `line[2]` and then use a `DateTimeFormatter` to extract the date and time from it into an individual `String` or you'd use `substring` too:

```
String date = line[2].substring(0,line[2].indexOf(' '));
String time = line[2].substring(line[2].indexOf(' '));
```

Problems: sovled.

There is no need to reverse the string at all. All the logic needed to parse these parsed values is done by using the `substring` and `indexOf` methods of the String class. No regular expressions needed.

Comment: *"All the logic needed ..."* would include the CSV library. --- My guess is that `provider = "Netflix"` and `note = "recharging of 987654321"`, `note = "game Of thrones"`, etc.

Comment: I guess you guessed better than I did ;)